# What do you say when you follow up?

Tags: job-search

I sent my resume to a couple of temp agencies, and I know that it's a good idea to follow up with some of them. I plan on calling, but I'm not sure exactly what to say. Should I just inquire on the status of my application and leave it at that?

Comment: "Should I just inquire on the status of my application and leave it at that?" - Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Hi, how are you doing today, this is "student".  I'm just calling to keep in touch and let you know I'm still very interested in this position.  Has there been any movement on your end?"  [person answers], "okay, thank you very much for your time, I won't hold you up.  Would it be okay if I called back next week around this time if I haven't heard anything?  Great, thank you very much [person's name].  Have a good day, Goodbye."