# How to reply to a status update for a job application?

Tags: communication, job-search, job-offer, hiring-process, applications

I've applied to a branding/design company for client service position. I'm communicating directly with the CEO, not a recruiter.

I made it through the interview and he said that he thinks that I'm a great fit with the brand and my experience would be very useful to their business. He wants to put me to their currently pitching project - and afterwards he will place me on that new project.

I've been communicating with him for quite a while, and he sent an email last week that he's hoping to come back to me this week to give me some sort of offer. Now, I got an email today and he said:

> Still no news I’m afraid, any news your side ?
>
> I am still very keen to discuss you joining our company,
>   however really need to hear back on a few projects before I can do
>   that.
>
> Looking forward to speaking soon.

So while I'm waiting to receive job offers, I'm currently having a part-time work for 3 weeks and after that (just in case a company would give me a job offer) I'd be available to work.

I'm pretty far in the interview process and I really want to work for this company, so I don't want to just give up and let this opportunity pass by. And I'm glad that the CEO is keeping me up to date, so it feels that he really wanted me to be part of his team.

How should I respond to his email? Should I ask if how many more days/week does he think should it take for me to start working? Should I also bring up that I'm currently having a part-time time and will be available to work after 3 weeks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you say when you follow up?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74188/what-do-you-say-when-you-follow-up)

Comment: That's not even close to being a duplicate. The question you reference has to do with following up with an prospect. This question is specifically asking about responding to a request as opposed to deciding when and how to spontaneously follow up.

Answer (score 2):

Respond with a positive email, thanking the CEO for the update and indicating that you are still very interested in a position with them and when you can start.

Dear CEO,

I appreciate you taking the time to provide me with a update.  Working with your company would be a fantastic opportunity for me because of (X,Y,Z).   Please let me know if there are any changes or additional information I can provide.  I am currently working a part time job for the next three weeks and will be available to start immediately after that time.

Thank you 
gee

Or something like that....

Comment: Or, if you can either work both, or leave the PT, then instead of putting 3 weeks, state the customary 2 weeks.